# Moving Ubuntu to a new hard drive, partitions reorganization

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, migration, fstab

I'm using Ubuntu on my laptop on a 250GB hard drive. I'm going to install a new 500GB hard drive and will create new partitions on it for different purposes.

Can I simply copy the partition where Ubuntu is installed to the new hard drive or will a reinstallation be needed? The first problem I find is that the fstab file should be rewritten.

What would you do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I tried to copy the partition directly and it looks that modifying the fstab file was the only thing needed.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand. You want to clone the image of your old hard drive and install it to your new drive.

If you are attempting to do this, I recommend [Clonezilla.](http://clonezilla.org/)
[Here](http://tuxradar.com/content/how-clone-hard-drives-clonezilla) is a tutorial of how to clone your hard drive.

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Nope. What do you undertand from "partitions reorganization" and "I'll create new partitions on it for different purposes"? I know how to copy the partition, but i'm going to create new partitions and delete others. What I ask is if it can affect the system.